# pyspark: join using schema? Or converting the schema to a list?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code to join two data frames:

```
new_df = df_1.join(df_2, on=['field_A', 'field_B', 'field_C'], how='left_outer')
```

The above code works fine, but sometimes `df_1` and `df_2` have hundreds of columns. Is it possible to join using the schema instead of manually adding all the columns? Or is there a way that I can transform the schema into a list? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't join on schema, if what you meant was somehow having `join` incorporate the column dtypes.  What you can do is extract the column names out first, then pass them through as the list argument for `on=`, like this:

```
join_cols = df_1.columns
df_1.join(df_2, on=join_cols, how='left_outer')
```

Now obviously you will have to edit the contents of `join_cols` to make sure it only has the names you actually want to join `df_1` and `df_2` on.  But if there are hundreds of valid columns that is probably much faster than adding them one by one.  You could also make join_cols an intersection of `df_1` and `df_2` columns, then edit from there if that's more suitable.

Edit: Although I should add that Spark 2.0 release is literally any day now, and I haven't versed myself on all the changes yet.  So that might be worth looking into also, or provide a future solution.